# Jquery not resizing image on slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, resize, slider, image-resizing

The problem is that I have an image larger than 477 x 205, but i'll need them for another things, it would be a problem to make 2 or 3 images with diferent sizes. So, I decided to resize it on jquery. The major problem is that i'm new on JQUERY ( please, be patient :B ).

I've read some of the topics, but none helped me, the one that got closer was to add "$('#slides').css('background-size', '477px 205px');":

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#slides').coinslider({ hoverPause: true });

    $('#slides').css('background-size', '477px 205px');

    $('#slides').css('overflow', 'hidden');
});
```

but, that didn't solve it, also, it starts at the right size, but when the slider starts looping, it gets a mess again

Comment: create a fiddle please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After 1 week without the solution, i've reached on what I was making mistakes, i was o the .js, when the Js loads, he create his own CSS for the slider, so I had to add the "background-size: *size*" on it like this:

```
// positioning squares
                    $("#cs-"+el.id+i+j).css({ 
                        'background-position': -sLeft +'px '+(-sTop+'px'),
                        'left' : sLeft ,
                        'top': sTop,
                        'background-size':'477px 205px' 
                    });
```

as it wasn't fixed a size to it, it would take the real size of the image as default.

Thank you for trying to help me with this issue!

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
 $('#slides').css('background-size', '477px 205px');
```

To this:

```
$('#slides').width(477).height(205);
```

The `overflow: hidden` will hide the rest of the image.

Answer (score 0):

More relevant code would be helpful in providing better guidance. Have you considered "background-size: cover" yet?

[Reference 1](http://www.css3.info/preview/background-size/),
[Reference 2](http://www.sitepoint.com/css3-background-size-property/)

Comment: i've tried your Jonny's code and it still doesn't fit on the slider ...

And using background doesn't really do the stuff, because i'm using a list of images, also, when it starts to run the background would just disappear.

Comment: It would be really helpful to see more code to be able to guide you better. Can you please create a Fiddle so that people can play around and suggest you the best solution?